# git push shows wrong username

Tags: git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I've looked up many posts on this but nothing helped.

There's a remote repo something like : `https://github.com/cakes/blue.git`

The global `gitconfig` is:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
        name = blake.shaw
[http]
        sslCaInfo = C:/bin/certificate.crt
```

This requires a certificate and hence put it as `http.sslCaInfo` and the certificate has been added to the git bin folder as well.

After cloning, the remote origin url was set to something like : `git@github.com:cakes/blue.git`

The id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are also created. The id_rsa.pub has been added to the ssh keys in github(remote).

When I try to do a `git push origin master`, it throws an error:

```
ERROR: Permission to cakes/blue.git denied to blake-shaw
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There are two issues:

1. The username in the url says `blake-shaw` instead of `blake.shaw`. How to reset it?
2. Tried using the url as : `https://github.com/cakes/blue.git` and using source tree, tried to push but then it throws the below error:

   ```
   remote: Permission to cakes/blue.git denied to blake.shaw.
   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/cakes/blue.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The username in the url says blake-shaw instead of blake.shaw. How to reset 
>   it?

Check that your  `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is registered to the github.com/blake.shaw account.

> Tried using the url as : https://github.com/cakes/blue.git

Check the user account used when pushing with SourceTree.

But more generally, make sure the repo `blue.git` is under `github.com/blake.shaw` user account, or it won't work (because blake.shaw is not the owner of the repo)

Comment: Thanks @VonC! The second one actually worked. I forked the repo and created a pull request. Regarding the first issue, I've registered the id_rsa to blake.shaw's account but then I guess I was trying to push to a repo for which i'm not the owner

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have any other files in the ~/.ssh directory besides the generated id_rsa and id_rsa.pub ?
2. The remote repo cloned should be copied in SSL mode in order to work properly (without having to put in the username and password everytime). Try cloning again using the SSL address- 
   `git clone git@github.com:cakes/blue.git`